# my servlet is not working i get an error HTTP404-not found but my jsp +html files are working fine

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm programming with java ee by eclipse .. suddenly my servlets are not working 
when i run my servlet i get "Http 404 -not found " error .
while my jsp + html files are working fine . 
ps:i checked  the port of tomcat and it is not used by another programme 
and i tried to restart the server and it didnt work

I'm using annotation "/servlet_name"
and i'm using the right url name:`http://localhost:8081/Project/servlet_name`

can u help me please !

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have entered a wrong url.if you are using annotation to config you should put this annotation on the class like this:

`@WebServlet(name = "one", urlPatterns = {"/test"})`

it means you should enter: `localhost:8081/Project/test`